# Comcast XfinityStream Android App APK Fire TV Stick

Tags: android

I have a Amazon Fire TV Stick (Gen 2) and I have been trying to sideload my Comcast XfinityStream APK to the device so I can watch live TV from the service I pay for.  It is successfully installed on the device, but when I open it, it just shows a black screen and goes back to the main menu on the Fire Stick.  I used a couple of the older versions, which up until recently worked fine, but they have since retired them and now none of them work.  I am trying to get their newest play store app release to work correctly.

My main question is this: what causes an Android app to open, show a black screen, and within no time, goes back to the main menu screen on an Android device, with no errors or messages displayed?  Does the Fire TV stick, being that is Android-based, have a directory where I check for logs of some sort when this type of app behavior happens?

Since the Fire TV stick is Android-based architecture on 5.x Lollipop, it should load up the same way as it does on my phone, in theory, but it doesn't.  I have downloaded the APK file and looked into the manifests file, but haven't seen anything in there or a few other places I've looked that could show some type of restriction or 'blacklisting', if you will, the Fire TV stick from being able to use it.  The API levels look correct as well as the hardware requirements.  Does anyone have an idea what this could be?  Here is the manifests file when it was decompiled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="40201001" android:versionName="4.2.1.001" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.xfinity.cloudtvr" platformBuildVersionCode="24" platformBuildVersionName="7.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature|signatureOrSystem" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:theme="0x7f0c010c" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="0x7f0200da" android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.XtvApplication" android:allowBackup="false" android:largeHeap="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:networkSecurityConfig="0x7f060001">
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0c010d" android:label="" android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.view.BrowseActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:windowSoftInputMode="20">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="@string/localytics_push_key" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.view.authentication.WebAuthCallbackHelperActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="@string/partner_continue_url_scheme" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.comcast.cim.android.view.launch.IntentForwardingActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="@string/deep_linking_scheme" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="@string/universal_deep_linking_scheme_1" />
                <data android:host="@string/universal_deep_linking_host_1" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="@string/universal_deep_linking_scheme_2" />
                <data android:host="@string/universal_deep_linking_host_1" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="LOCALYTICS_APP_KEY" android:value="@string/localytics_app_key" />
        <receiver android:name="com.localytics.android.ReferralReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.localytics.android.PushTrackingActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.localytics.android.GcmListenerService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.localytics.android.InstanceIDListenerService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.xfinity.common.analytics.LocalyticsCrashReportingIntentService" android:exported="false" />
        <activity android:name="com.xfinity.common.view.LaunchActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0c0200" android:label="" android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.view.authentication.EligibilityCheckActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:windowSoftInputMode="10" />
        <activity android:name="com.comcast.cim.android.view.settings.SignoutActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0c010e" android:label="" android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.view.PlayerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="20" android:parentActivityName="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.view.BrowseActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".view.BrowseActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0c0203" android:label="@string/settings" android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.view.settings.XtvSettingsActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.inhome.ConnectionChangedBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.downloads.XtvDownloadService" android:exported="false" />
        <service android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.downloads.XtvDownloadsNotificationReceiver$XtvNotificationBuilderService" android:exported="false" />
        <service android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.model.resumepoint.ResumePointSyncIntentService" android:exported="false" />
        <service android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.model.user.parentalcontrols.ParentalControlsSyncIntentService" android:exported="false" />
        <service android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.downloads.DownloadUpdateService" android:exported="false" />
        <service android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.downloads.DownloadPermCacheReloadService" android:exported="false" />
        <activity android:name="com.xfinity.cloudtvr.view.settings.SettingsWebViewActivity" />
        <service android:name="com.xfinity.common.user.FavoritesSyncIntentService" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme_IAPTheme" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:exported="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have been looking at this in notepad, so don't have the best view to look at all of the code and I am sort of new to Android coding and app development so I am just trying to see if anyone else who develops apps more in depth would know where to look and how to possibly fix the issue.  I have tried installing Android System Webview and Google Chrome on the Fire TV stick without issues and that is what made the app work in its previous versions that have now since been retired.

Does anyone know where or what I could look for in the decompiled code or files that may impact/restrict the app when it is trying to start on the Fire TV Stick?

Here is the APK file version I am using: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/comcast/xfinity-stream/xfinity-stream-4-2-1-001-release/xfinity-stream-4-2-1-001-android-apk-download/

I am sure this thread will be of much needed help for others as well because there are a bunch of people who have sideloaded this app and who are now experiencing this issue trying to get a new APK file up and running on the Fire TV Stick.